# How can I remove the condensate pump from a Miele dryer?

Tags: dryer, pump, removal

I can't figure out how to remove the condensate pump of a Miele tumbler dryer. 
The pump is locate at the center bottom at the back of the dryer. I can shift it back and forth a bit, but don't see any obvious way to detach it.

It looks like this:

[image: miele t4463 condensate pump]

Left corner behind the pump
[image: behind the pump]

Right corner behind the pump
[image: Behind the pump]

From below
[image: pump from below]

In 3 corners the pump is held down in plastic brackets, which would seem to indicate that it sould be removed by a rotating movement.
But i can find anything holding it stuck in the fourth corner:

[image: the fourth corner]

Comment: As I just repaired a Miele dish washer: The newer ones have a part at the bottom that you can un-screw and can pull out for easier access. Hopefully that's the case for your machine as well. You might want to take some photos from the inside as well as it's quite hard to tell that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the left corner (2nd photograph), push down the lip a bit with your finger, then it easily swivels out.
Clean out the stuff in the reservoir.
You can remove the part that the hose attaches to as well, be sure to put back the ball back into this part, it serves as a anti-back-flow valve

Comment: Thanks, that was the magic trick i was looking for. And as i expected, the reservoir below was full of junk.

Comment: It took me a long time to work out what you meant, but yes, this is it! In the middle of photo two is a tab that goes down under the arch. The whole mechanism comes forward